# Forking - Number of children

Tags: c, fork

So I have a to make a function that takes in an argument n which is an int representing the number of children to be forked, and will print the pid of all the children that have been forked. So the goal of this function is to fork n children and each child prints out its pid. I am new to forking and not sure how to accomplish such a task.

Thank you in advance for any help you provide :)

This is what i have now, it seems to be working, but the program never ends once its finished. What should I do

```
 void print_child_pid(int n) {
int i;
pid_t pid; 
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
        /* error handling here, if needed */
        return;
    }
    if (pid == 0) {
        printf("child: process id = %d\n", getpid());
        wait();
        return;
    }
}

return;
```

}

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Perhaps you should look up the documentation on the `fork` function.

Comment: Show your code and what's not working on it.

Comment: @GWW I have tried the code

Comment: @chrk I added the code, its not exiting out though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close but you are calling `wait` in the child process when you should be calling `waitpid` in the parent process.  There is a nice explanation of this on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28system_call%29#Example_in_C).  I've modified your code below to use it.

```
void print_child_pid(int n) {
    int i;
    pid_t pid; 
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        pid = fork();
        if (pid == -1) {
            /* error handling here, if needed */
        }
        if (pid == 0) {
            printf("child: process id = %d\n", getpid());
            return;
        }else{
            int status;
            (void)waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Output with n = 4:

```
child: process id = 9363
child: process id = 9364
child: process id = 9365
child: process id = 9366
```

Comment: Ah Yes!, the only thing missing here is return; after printf("child: process ......);